# How to add values from an array in bash with a for loop

Tags: arrays, bash, nested-loops, imagemagick-convert

My goal is to automate the annotation feature in convert (Imagemagick) for myself. Running the script in a folder with some images: I try to read a text file with the annotation titles, each on a new line.
Then read the file into an array. (maybe there is a better way?)

I am not able to understand how to add each value of the array and loop through all the images in the folder.

Here is the script so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

## content of file.txt
sample 1
sample 2
sample 3
sample 4
sample 5
sample 6
sample 7
sample 8
sample 9

## Read from a file into an array, print the array
array=()

# Read the file in parameter and fill the array named "array"
getArray() {
    i=0
    while read line # Read a line
    do
    array[i]=$line # Put it into the array
    i=$(($i + 1))
    done < $1
}

getArray "file.txt"

## Here my problems start

for f in *.jpg; do fn=${f%.*};

    for e in "${array[@]}";do

    convert ${fn}.jpg -fill white -gravity South -pointsize 32 -annotate +0+5 "$e" ${fn}_annotated.jpg ;done

done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
# Store the whole file in an array
readarray array < "file.txt" || exit 1

i=0
for f in *.jpg ; do
    fn=${f%.*}
    title=${array[i++]}   # in array[] bash performs arithmetic expansion

    convert "$fn.jpg" -fill white -gravity South -pointsize 32 \
        -annotate +0+5 "$title" "${fn}_annotated.jpg"
done
```

Comment: Thank you Edouard, it works very nice for such a simple solution.